# How to write SQL that can give the following result?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, crosstab

Original table

```
+------------+---------+-------+-------------+--------+
| CampaignID | Medium  | Month | Impressions | Clicks |
+------------+---------+-------+-------------+--------+
| A          | Google  | Jan   |          15 |      2 |
| B          | Google  | Jan   |          12 |      1 |
| A          | YouTube | Jan   |          11 |      2 |
| B          | YouTube | Jan   |          12 |      4 |
| A          | Google  | Feb   |          15 |      3 |
| B          | Google  | Feb   |          13 |      4 |
| A          | YouTube | Feb   |          12 |      2 |
| B          | YouTube | Feb   |          21 |      5 |
+------------+---------+-------+-------------+--------+
```

Expected result

```
+-----------+--------------------+---------------+---------------------+----------------+
| CampainID | Google Impressions | Google Clicks | YouTube Impressions | YouTube Clicks |
+-----------+--------------------+---------------+---------------------+----------------+
| A         |                 30 |             5 |                  23 |              4 |
| B         |                 25 |             4 |                   3 |             39 |
+-----------+--------------------+---------------+---------------------+----------------+
```

The number of values in the medium need to be generated at run time. This means that the number of columns in the query result are **dynamic** dependent on the data. What would be the most elegant solution in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1):

You can query this way:

```
WITH Src AS
(
SELECT * FROM (VALUES
  ('A', 'Google' , 'Jan', 15, 2),
  ('B', 'Google' , 'Jan', 12, 1),
  ('A', 'YouTube', 'Jan', 11, 2),
  ('B', 'YouTube', 'Jan', 12, 4),
  ('A', 'Google' , 'Feb', 15, 3),
  ('B', 'Google' , 'Feb', 13, 4),
  ('A', 'YouTube', 'Feb', 12, 2),
  ('B', 'YouTube', 'Feb', 21, 5)) T(CampaignID, Medium, Month, Impressions, Clicks)
) --End sample data

SELECT CampaignID,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Medium='Google' THEN Impressions ELSE 0 END) "Google Impessions",
  SUM(CASE WHEN Medium='Google' THEN Clicks ELSE 0 END) "Google Clicks",
  SUM(CASE WHEN Medium='YouTube' THEN Impressions ELSE 0 END) "YouTube Impessions",
  SUM(CASE WHEN Medium='YouTube' THEN Clicks ELSE 0 END) "YouTube Clicks"
FROM Src
GROUP BY CampaignID
```

Comment: But I do not know how many values are there for Medium. Tomorrow I could have another Medium called `Facebook` but the solution I develop now has to be good enough for that case. ie, the new result should have 2 additional columns.